# How to merge order by records from two different queries in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2016

Following scenario, in which I need top 3 records from the same table with specific condition and need to merge with second query records with excluding first query result.

Table A:

```
    Id  Name Flag
    -------------
    1    A    1
    2    B    0
    3    C    0
    4    D    1
    5    E    0
    6    F    1
    7    G    0
    8    H    0
```

Top 3 where flag = 1 with latest records page index 1 and row count 5

```
   Id   Name Flag
  ----------------
    6    F    1
    4    D    1         first require flag  =1 first 3 records
    1    A    1
    ---------------------------------------
    8    H    0
    7    G    0
```

Page index 2 and row count 5 with latest records

```
    Id  Name Flag
    --------------
    6    F    1
    5    E    0
    3    C    0
    2    B    0
```

How can I achieve this with a SQL query?

```
IF (@PageNumber = 0)  
BEGIN  
    SELECT TOP (@RowsPerPage) [Id], [Name], [Flag] 
    FROM  
        (SELECT [Id], [Name], [Flag]  
         FROM 
             (SELECT TOP 3 [Id], [Name], [Flag]  
              FROM [A] 
              WHERE Flag = 1 
              ORDER BY Id DESC

              UNION             

              SELECT [Id], [Name], [Flag] 
              FROM [A] 
              ORDER BY Id DESC) T
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN 
        // Normal paging query excluding top 3 flag records.
    END
```

Comment: i see id 6 is present in both result sets

Comment: Yes, it is typo, it will not there

Comment: please check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        Seq1 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Flag ORDER BY Id DESC),
        Seq2 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id DESC),
        Id,
        Name,
        Flag
        FROM t1     
)
SELECT
Seq1,
id,
name,
flag
FROM CTE
  WHERE Seq1 < 4

 UNION ALL

 SELECT
Seq2,
id,
name,
flag
FROM CTE
  WHERE Seq1 >3
  ORDER BY 4 desc,1
```